# NSMutableArray returns null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView that gets populated my a NSMutableArray. This is how I have it set up in my .h

```
@interface processViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *processList;
}

@property (copy, readwrite) NSMutableArray *processList;
```

and my .m

```
@synthesize processList;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

I put a NSLog on it on the viewDidLoad, and it displays just fine. But after I run a action, the `processList` array returns `null`. Any ideas why?

Thanks
Coulton

**EDIT 1:**

```
- (void)startUploads {

// Start UIActivity in the top
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

// Start Pool
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

// Display results for testing purposes (commented out)
NSArray *resultstwo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM processes"];
for (NSDictionary *rowtwo in resultstwo) {

    // Get ID
    int getUserIDcount = 0;
    NSArray *getUserIDInfo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM login"];
    for (NSDictionary *getUserIDRow in getUserIDInfo) {
        getUserIDcount++;
        NSString *oneUserID = [getUserIDRow valueForKey:@"id"];
        theUserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", oneUserID];
    }

    // If theUserID exists...
    if (getUserIDcount == 0) {
        //myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector: @selector(checkLogin) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
    } else {


        // Get URL of image
        NSString *sqlImageUploadPathOne = @"./../Documents/";
        NSString *sqlImageUploadPathTwo = [rowtwo valueForKey:@"image"];
        NSString *getAlbumID = [rowtwo valueForKey:@"album"];
        NSString *sqlImageUploadPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",sqlImageUploadPathOne,sqlImageUploadPathTwo];

        //testLabel.text = @"Uploading...";

        // Display Image in UIImageView (uploadImageHidden)
        UIImage *attemptImage = [UIImage imageNamed:sqlImageUploadPath];
        [uploadImageHidden setImage:attemptImage];



        // Upload to server
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImageHidden.image, 90);
        NSString *urlStringOne = @"http://myflashpics.com/iphone_processes/upload.php?album=";
        NSString *urlStringTwo = @"&id=";
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",urlStringOne,getAlbumID,urlStringTwo,theUserID];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

        if ([returnString rangeOfString:@"yes"].location == NSNotFound) {
            // Fail
        } else {
            // Delete image if successful
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
            NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:sqlImageUploadPathTwo];
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:myFilePath error:NULL];
            [database executeNonQuery:@"DELETE FROM processes WHERE image=?", sqlImageUploadPathTwo];

            // Get Photo ID
            NSArray *myWords = [returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            NSString *photoID = [myWords objectAtIndex:1]; 
            NSString *usernameID = [myWords objectAtIndex:2]; 

            NSString *defaultName = @"Photo uploaded from the flashpics iPhone application";

            // Get Thumbnail URL
            NSString *thumbnailURLOne = @"http://myflashpics.com/users/";
            NSString *thumbnailURLTwo = @"/pictures/thumbnails/";
            NSString *thumbnailURLThree = @".jpg";
            NSString *thumbnailURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",thumbnailURLOne,usernameID,thumbnailURLTwo,photoID,thumbnailURLThree];

            // Download thumbnail
            //NSLog(@"Downloading...");
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL]]];
            //NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);
            NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            //NSLog(@"%@",docDir);
            //NSLog(@"saving jpeg");
            NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_thumbnail.jpg",docDir,photoID];
            NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
            [data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];
            //NSLog(@"saving image done");
            [image release];

            // Put in database
            NSString *thumbnailEnd = @"_thumbnail.jpg";
            NSString *thumbnailLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photoID,thumbnailEnd];

            int theCount = 0;
            NSArray *getUserIDInfotoo = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=?",photoID];
            for (NSDictionary *getUserIDRowtoo in getUserIDInfotoo) {
                theCount++;
            }

            if (theCount == 0) {
                [database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO images (id, name, thumbnail, album) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", photoID, defaultName, thumbnailLocation, getAlbumID];
            }
            //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateImages) toTarget:RootViewController withObject:nil];
            //myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector: @selector(updateImages) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
        }

        [request release];
        [returnString release];

    }

    //NSLog([rowtwo valueForKey:@"image"]);
    //NSLog([rowtwo valueForKey:@"album"]);
}


[pool release];

// Stop the UIActivity in the top bar
TableViewAppDelegate *dataCeter = (TableViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([dataCeter.dataTen isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Where the startUploads gets called (different .m)

```
processViewController *processTable = [[processViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"processView.xib" bundle:nil];
[processTable startUploads];
[processTable release];
```

Comment: What is "a action"? It's pretty important to know what it is you're doing between the time the array is valid and the time it is invalid.

Comment: @Marc The [cocoa] tag is for Cocoa on Mac OS. For iOS, use [cocoa-touch] instead.

Comment: @Mark W: Just posted my code that happens.

Comment: Don't see were processList gets set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More code would be helpful but here are some suggestions:

1. Check if `startUploads` is being called before the view is loaded. The view will only be loaded when it is accessed for the first time to be added to a superview.
2. Consider initializing `processList` in your `init` method instead of `viewDidLoad` both to solve #1 and b/c the view can loaded & unloaded by iOS independently of the lifecycle of the viewController (depending on what other views you are displaying and whether any memory warnings occur).
3. Make sure you are releasing `processList` in `dealloc`. You only need to release it in `viewDidUnload` if it is recreated and loaded in `viewDidLoad`.

Your code sample doesn't show when `startUploads` is being called and you aren't adding any items to `processList` so it's hard to tell if the above is relevant. Post some more code and I'll revise my answer accordingly.

good luck!

[EDIT: added example code]

The code fragments you posted are not a complete implementation of a view controller and the associated objects that interact with it. Given the code I have seen, your application design does not conform to MVC (Model/View/Controller) design pattern and I would be doing things a bit differently. However, I don't want to make assumptions about code I haven't seen or your ultimate intent or ability as a developer. I can't write your app for you, just trying to directly help you with the specific question you asked regarding why your NSMutableArray property remains null after the `startUploads` action completed. With that in mind, here are my edits to the code you posted:

processViewController.m - add the following:

```
- (id)initWithNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    self = [super initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:bundle];
    if (self) {
        processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.processList = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

different.m

```
- (void)displayProcessVC {
    ProcessViewController *processVC = [[ProcessViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"processView.xib" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC BEFORE STARTING UPLOAD, processList = %@", processVC.processList);
    [processVC startUploads];
    NSLog(@"Different:displayProcessVC AFTER STARTING UPLOAD, processList = %@", processVC.processList);
    // would normally present process VC here
    [processVC release];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, so my answer is valid. your problem looks like #2. You need to allocate `processList` in `initWithNibName:`, not in `viewDidLoad`. The view is not loaded yet when `startUploads` is called. Your example doesn't make much sense b/c you are initializing processTable and never presenting it. `processViewController` would typically be presented modally or pushed onto a navigation controller before being released.

Comment: Ok, so if I do it like this: `processTable.processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, it won't work. When the viewDidLoad it opened, it outputs NULL in the console. I also put it in my `-(id)init { processList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; }` and it doesn't get called when ever `startUploads` does (put a NSLog the init and it doesn't show up until the view is opened).

Comment: When I said to consider initializing processList in your init method I didn't literally mean `-(id)init`. In this case you are using `-(id)initWithNibName:` so you need to do it there. Override the superclass implementation and initialize `processList` there. I recommend reading Apple's View Controller Programming Guide and specifically the sections on the View Controller life cycle.

Comment: Again, excuse my noob-ish comments. I really have only been looking and working with Xcode for over 2 months. I have looked all over and I still can't seem to find a cure to this. Do I put it in the view I am loading or the view it's loading from? Could you also provide some example code if it's not too hard. Thanks!